# how i add collaborators side-view in atmosphere?

Tags: meteor

i saw collaborators side-view in some (mrt, tmeasday) atmosphere organisation, is there any way to add like view in other organisations in atmosphere or is it exclusive for them ?

[image]

Comment: surely if you've collaborated on a package, collaborators will also come up for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add maintainers to the package like this

```
meteor admin maintainers <yourusername-or-organization:your-package> --add <collaborator-username>

meteor admin maintainers iron:router --add mrt
```

Then their name will be shown in collaborators/contributors list